# standard deviation and mode

Tags: php

i finished the standard deviation...but there are still discrepancies i can't resolve...when i calculate the standard deviation manually..the answer is different from the output of my system.. >.<

while for the mode..i used an array..this is my code:

```
$sample = array($one[$ctr],$two[$ctr],$three[$ctr],$four[$ctr],$five[$ctr],$six[$ctr],$seven[$ctr],$eight[$ctr],$nine[$ctr],$ten[$ctr],$fda[$ctr]);

rsort($sample);
$holder = $sample[0];
//$holder = $mode;
```

the sorting is successful..and i can get the highest number...but..i need to print the value of $holder to a table using fpdf....

but..when i try to run the system..the value of $holder...is not printed in the table...any idea on how i can print the $holder's value..or..why the value is not visible in the table?? >.< thanks again... :)

Comment: Please improve your question!   There is apparently no direct relationship to StdDev nor Mod, the issue appears to be related to managing the output.  Yet there is no code snippet related to this output logic...

Comment: my question is about the mode...

Answer (score 0):

For standard deviation, try something like

```
$count = count($sample);
$avg = array_sum($sample) / $count;

$standardDividend = 0;

foreach($sample as $val)
    $standardDividend += (pow(($val - $avg), 2));

$standardDev = pow(($standardDividend / $count), .5);
```

Theoretically should work.

As far as mode goes, you're using the wrong sort. `rsort()` sorts from highest to lowest, not from most present to least present. So a `$sample`

```
$sample = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 15);

rsort($sample);

$mode = = $sample[0];
```

Would equal 15, not 1 as expected. Instead, try:

```
$mode = arsort(array_count_values($sample));
$mode = $sample[0];
```

This will return the first mode found. If there is more than one mode, it will only return one. Also, it will always return something, even if no mode exists. But it's a start.

Comment: >> i used rsort because i need to put the highest value in index[0]..from your example..15 is the highest..so i need to put 15 on index[0]...i'm not sorting the index of the array, thus the values inside the array...so that when 15 is in index[0] i can assign it in a variable so that i can print it on a pdf table(fpdf)...the problem is..i can't print the the value of index[0] in the table.. >.<